# When should JavaScript NOT be gzipped?

Tags: javascript, gzip

I've noticed that some big-name sites serve JavaScript that is compressed and some that is not compressed, on the same page load.

I also [read](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-minification-and-gzipping/#comment-1596136) that JavaScript shouldn't be gzipped when served over https. To back this up, I noticed that when serving jQuery from Google's CDN they only serve it compressed from HTTP, but not from HTTPS.

e.g. the first is compressed; the second is not.

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"
```

However, if you pull jQuery from the Microsoft CDN over https:

```
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js
```

it IS served compressed.

Examples of big sites that serve both compressed and uncompressed on the same page load, regardless of HTTPS or not:

- https://wordpress.com — serves 19 compressed, 2 not.
- http://stackoverflow.com — serves 9 compressed, 1 not
- https://www.microsoft.com — serves 10 compressed, 6 not

So my question is: when should I gzip my JavaScript and when should I not?

Note, the question at [Can you use gzip over SSL? And Connection: Keep-Alive headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767211/can-you-use-gzip-over-ssl-and-connection-keep-alive-headers) is somewhat similar, in that the answers there explain under what circumstances compression should NOT be used under HTTPS. However, that's only half my question — some HTTP (not HTTPS) sites also compress some but not all of their javascript resources e.g. the Stackoverflow example mentioned above.

Comment: The things mentioned have to do with transferring _secure_ content. A lot of javascript isn't considered secure (ie. it's something anyone can get by just visiting the page), and thus not worthy of concern. However, if you are serving secure content (ie. a json payload with identifiable information), then you should not gzip it.

Comment: @willaien any idea what implications would be when it is gzip'd?

Comment: I believe it should not be gzipped over https when you need to support IE6. I don't remember where I read that so I'll leave this as comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @charlietfl According to the wikipedia article, and a tiny bit of research, it appears that there are ways to glean a bit of information about what's been sent if the data is compressed. That said, if you're already minifying, gzipping doesn't offer much extra compression. If you're burning through enough bandwidth to care, you're asking the wrong crowd.

Comment: It should be noted that, if the javascript payload is being served on the same domain name (regardless of server) that *does* handle sensitive information, all compression should be turned off for that domain, if any of the data is held clientside via cookies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use gzip over SSL? And Connection: Keep-Alive headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767211/can-you-use-gzip-over-ssl-and-connection-keep-alive-headers)

Comment: @willaien _if you're already minifying, gzipping doesn't offer much extra compression._ dude I think you have that backwards.

Comment: @willaien: Minifying a 100k js file in my experience will usually get you an 80k file. Gzipping that 100k file will normally give you a 10k file -- that's a big difference in my book. And gzipping a minified 100k file will usually give you an 8k file.

Comment: "the second is not." --- it actually is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initially I thought that it has something to do with old browser support as indeed IE6 and Netscape4 had bugs when handling compressed js files. But that had nothing to do with HTTPS. It was compression itself and server config files have long had conditional settings to not compress js files if an older browser is detected.

After some googling, it turns out that the issue is not with js. It is with HTTPS. **You should not serve gzipped content over HTTPS/SPDY/HTTP2**. There are two attacks that are possible when you serve gzipped content over HTTPS:  [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) and [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_(security_exploit)).

Both CRIME and BREACH attacks make use of the fact that gzipping data reduce their size in statistically predictable ways. Both attacks are able to extract cookies which, depending on how your site works, allows an attacker to login to user accounts.

So from your observation we can conclude that the google CDN is correctly configured.

However, do note how both attacks work: their ultimate aim is session hijacking. If you're downloading a js/css/gif file from a Microsoft server then your browser won't be sending your site's cookies along with the request (same-origin policy). So Microsoft can be forgiven for serving compressed js files on HTTPS.

Which means that you **can** serve compressed files over HTTPS! You just need to make sure those files come from a different domain to prevent CRIME and BREACH attacks from stealing your cookies.

Comment: `content-encoding:gzip` --- this is what I see when I request https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: To test this initially, I put those two jQuery URLs into script tags in an empty html document and examined Safari's developer tools' network tab. In the right-hand-sidebar, under "request and response", "Compressed" is "No" for the latter. Doing it in curl explicitly sending "Accept-Encoding: gzip" and yes indeed, it comes back compressed. Is this a browser default not to ask for compression on https resources?

Comment: @jeff-h: Probably. But it doesn't explain why Microsoft returns compressed files.

Comment: This is an excellent answer when running HTTPS. However, I'm still intrigued as to why some HTTP sites serve both compressed and uncompressed JavaScript. If nothing surfaces on that angle I'll mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Then, tools like Google Lighthouse should stop attributing low scores when HTTPS content is not gzipped!