# Is gzip compression with https possible in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, https, compression, gzip

Is it possible to configure Tomcat (7.0.75) for https and enable gzip compression *simultaneously*?  I can't figure out a valid combination of http connector properties in `server.xml` to get the job done. The four compression-related properties that work on http:

```
compression="on"
compressableMimeType="application/json"
compressionMinSize="8192"
useSendfile="false"
```

don't seem to have any effect when https is configured. My current config:

```xml
<Connector port="8443"
  protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  SSLEnabled="true"
  maxThreads="50"
  server="web"
  allowTrace="false"
  keystoreFile="/app/certs/keystore.jks"
  keystorePass="********"
  scheme="https"
  secure="true"
  clientAuth="false"
  sslProtocol="TLS"
  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" 
  ciphers="TLS_..._SHA"
  maxKeepAliveRequests="100"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  compression="on"
  compressableMimeType="application/json"
  compressionMinSize="8192"
  useSendfile="false"
  maxSwallowSize="-1"
  socket.soKeepAlive="true"/>
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767211/can-you-use-gzip-over-ssl-and-connection-keep-alive-headers

Answer (score 6):

I use this configuration of **server.xml**:

**1. http connector**

```xml
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
    compression="on" compressionMinSize="0" useSendfile="false"
    redirectPort="443" />
```

**2. https connector**

```xml
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" connectionTimeout="20000"
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="0" useSendfile="false" >
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/key.crt"
                     certificateFile="conf/certificate.crt"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/chain.crt"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

You may want to change port `80` to `8080`, and port `443` to `8443`.

---

**UPD:** If you use `http2` protocol - add this line too:

```xml
<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"
                 compression="on" compressionMinSize="0" useSendfile="false" />
```